# Combine Hibernate Criteria API with Lucene via Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

How can can I combine hibernate criteria API with Lucene hibernate search?

```
org.hibernate.Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.ne(property, value));

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftm.createFullTextQuery(booleanQuery, class);

fullTextQuery.setCriteriaQuery(criteria);

Object result = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

In the above example hibernate isn't respecting the restrictions?

Comment: Can anyone please check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776214/lucene-hibernate-full-text-search

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.4/api/org/hibernate/search/FullTextQuery.html#setCriteriaQuery(org.hibernate.Criteria)) no where restriction can be defined in the criteria set in FullTextQuery. As you are using a BooleanQuery, you can add to it a clause with the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using a wrong instance of Criteria? You add a restriction to `criteria`, but use the `hibernateCriteria` on other places

Comment: Ooh its in the example only.. its the same criteria